# Most efficient: different functions / one function with cases

Tags: javascript, function, performance

What would be the most efficient in JS?
different functions / one function (extra parameter) with cases, if i had say 10 cases.

Here the question was already asked once but imho the question "what is the most efficient" was not really answered.
[Two functions, or one function with different params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837293/two-functions-or-one-function-with-different-params)

Comment: I would pick whatever is most readable. Performance differences are probably negligible here.

Comment: What kind of performance issues are you running into? I would say that using multiple functions eases the readability and structure of the code - but my guess would be function are slower. Is it a issue or just a speculation?

Comment: There is absolutely no issue and for readability i agree, but while i'm developing (and learning) i'd like to be sure if i'm doing things the right way :-)

Comment: Readability is the right way. No such thing as correct unreadable code, outside of academia, unless the obfusaction was a deliberate choice. Course the fun bit is one man's readable, is another's "What idiot wrote this?"

Comment: Use [jsperf](http://jsperf.com) to do tests of different implementation techniques. Then, as Joe Armstrong says about such questions concerning Erlang, "just write the most beautiful program you can."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I wouldn't worry much about efficiency in such a high level example. what I *would* worry about is what approach would fit more in an extensibility sense (ala, the [expression problem](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ExpressionProblem)).

**Functions that deal with the cases inside make it easier to add new kinds of function** but make it harder to add a new kind of case (you would need to edit each existing function to do so).

On the other hand, **functions/methods that are separate for each case make it easier to add new cases but make it harder to add a new kinds of function** (since you would need to go back to each kind of case and add the new method to it)

Comment: That is a nice, nuanced answer, Thx